# How do I exclude transient dependency from jar file in gradle?

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have an android project that has a dependency to SDK that is available in jar file so I've put it in `lib` folder but that `jar` file contains `gson` library in it and it seams is outdate. So I'd like to exclude it and add separate dependency to gson.

how can I do this?
thanks

UPD

```
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.code.gson', module: 'gson'
}
```

results in error

```
Error:(49, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'exclude()'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude it explicityly from the dependency like this:

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar', excludes: ['gson-stuff'])
```

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: sorry it is not available for `fileTree`
so when I try it like this 
`compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.code.gson', module: 'gson'
    }`
it says `Error:(49, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'exclude()'`

Comment: if i do it like this `compile fileTree(
            include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs',
            excludes: [group: 'com.google.code.gson', module: 'gson']
    )` it says `Error:(49, 0) Cannot cast object '{group=com.google.code.gson, module=gson}' with class 'java.util.LinkedHashMap' to class 'java.lang.Iterable' due to: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: java.lang.Iterable(java.util.LinkedHashMap)`

and BTW I think `excludes` param is for excluding some files or folders and not sure if it will exclude internal dependency on jar file....